# How do I sign out of iCloud on iOS6

Tags: icloud

How do I sign out of iCloud on iOS6.

I have created a 2nd AppleID I want to use for iCloud synching, but the only option I get is "Delete Account". I don't want to delete the AppleID (which is used on other devices), just change to the new account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My old link for this dried up, but delete account is really "delete this account from my device".    The text of [this article](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/19/how-to-delete-icloud-account-ios/) confirms that, but unfortunately I can't find an apple.com link currently.

Reading [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6720407?start=0&tstart=0) will also confirm it for you, although indirectly.